How do I mount resource directories into my docker image via Cromwell / WDL?
Problem is that the docker image i am trying to run requires a mount points to several resources in order to run. Example:
docker 
  --rm 
  -v /path/to/dir/a:/opt/mnt/a/ 
  -v /path/to/dir/b/:/opt/mnt/b/ 
  -i 
image:1.0.0 /bin/bash -c "cmd -a /opt/mnt/a/ -b /opt/mnt/b -o output/"

How to specify this within WDL task
version 1.0

workflow {
  #...
}


task MyTask {
  input {
    String fin
  }
  command <<<
   #????
  >>>
  output {
    File out = "./output"
  }
  runtime {
    docker: "image:1.0.0"
    # what should be specified here ?
  }
}
```

